# Excel Upload to database table

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, etl

I'm looking for the best solution to allow our users to upload XLS spreadsheet so that they can be used to populate tables in our data warehouse (DW).

Our users are heavy Business Object (BO) users, and BO lets you export to XLS. When they have data in a spreadsheet that needs to be loaded to the DW, they need a process to upload the data in the XLS to the DW's db. As a result, we end up with many of these "interfaces" when I think that what we really need is a programmatic automated feed. Using Excel as a data source for inter-system feeds, in my gut, just seems like a bad idea to me.

Question #1: I'd like to see if you agree and why or why not.

OK, there is no swimming against that tide, so I now take as a given that XLS uploads are here to stay for us. Now I need to find the best solution. First, I'll explain what we do now and then what I don't like about it:

Via web pages, we provide empty XLS files (no rows) with a defined set of columns. Each file is intended to be used to update a different target dest table. In each spreadsheet is an "upload" button. Pushing the Upload button results in the macro in the spreadsheet serializing the contents of the file to CSV and FTPing the data to server folder. Periodically, a scheduler fires off an Informatica ETL job that uses the CSV file as input and loads the data into a custom XLS-specific staging table and then, if the records pass edits, into the appropriate target table. Any errors encountered are logged to an error table. For each XLS file uploaded, the data ends up in a separate staging and error table that is specific for the file.

Some of the things I don't like include about our process are:

1) The macro code in the XLS is too exposed, includes passwords for example, can be tampered with and there are issues ensuring that the users are using the latest XLS templates.
2) Business Rule edits are placed in the ETL program, where they should probably be, but because we would like to catch the errors ASAP, i.e, in the spreadsheet, edits are also added to the macro code. This results in duplication of business edits. I want these rules in one place and centrally controlled. IMHO, I think putting any macro code in the XLS introduces a maintenance issue, even calls to stored procedures (some of which we have) or calls to web services (we haven't yet tried to call .NET Web Services from XLS macros.)
3) Every XLS file upload template has its own process with distinct set of staging and error tables and a custom screen for reporting errors encountered. It seems like we need a more generalized re-usable solution.

Besides often getting data exported to XLS from BO, the users like also  Excel because it is easier to edit a large number of records and less clunkier than editing individual records via a web interface.

This is the general direction that I am thinking:

First, I want the users to have the ease of editing of Excel with editing, but without including embedded macros in the spreadsheet. I experimented with Farpoint's Grid with Excel compatibility...

http://www.fpoint.com/netproducts/spreadweb/tour/excel.aspx

...and I found that it was quite easy to allow a user the ability to open up an XLS file that resides on their PC and have it open up in a browser and be able to easily access the data read from server-side .NET web code. Excel isn't running locally in their browser, but the functionality of Excel is reproduced, presumably through a lot of client sided scripting that I expect would be a real pain to duplicate myself. You can even cut and paste from a local spreadsheet into the web's spreadsheet. This sounds great, by biggest problem is cost. Our company is near death and won't allow us to purchase any new software.

Next, I want to identify the common components across all spreadsheet upload processing and come up with generic processing code. For example, I imagine a table which defines each of our spreadsheets and the format of each including the column names and data type definitions, perhaps in terms of their destination columns instead of hard coding.  Based on this table template definition, I can generate XLS templates for download from this table definition. I can also perform simple generic edits to ensure that the data entered matches the table definition. And one common web page can be used to present the data and allow report data type mismatch errors and allow for the user to correct them. I would also define a common table for storing the data in a "staging" table, using a table with two columns, submission #, row num, name and value, perhaps. No more "custom everything" is the goal.

Next I need to decide where to put the business rules. My dept's mgt firmly believes that all loading of data should be done by Informatica ETL batch processes and therefore the rules/edits belong "in Informatica". I have zero experience with Informatica tools, I am more of a .NET guy. I am therefore unsure as to how these rules are implemented but I suspect that they are not reusable in the sense that they can be used by a .NET web page to    validate a particular record against. You see, in some cases, when the user is not performing a bulk upload, they do have the ability to edit a specific record and I would like the same edits that were applied by the ETL bulk insert process to be applied to an individual update attempt to a single record via a web page. If the solution to write a single web service or stored procedure that can be called from either the web page doing an update of a single record or called thousands of times for each record in a bulk upload? The latter sounds inefficient.

Your thoughts on anything above would be very much welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a cost perspective, the efforts you'll need to go through to re-create spreadsheet functionality on the web will exceed the cost of Farpoint or other controls.  Even if you made $20 an hour, do you think you could complete a working product in under 2 weeks?  I think you have the facts on your side when you discussed maintenance issues if you allow ETL functionality to exist in Excel - you have twice the amount of work to maintain the transformation rules.  I think you need to convince management that in order to create a maintainable, robust solution you need some flexible utilities.

Farpoint is a good choice.  There is also [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com) that is a .Net engine that interprets Excel macros and can run on a web server.  It has a Win32 control that allows you to create a WinForms solution with very Excel interface functionality.  Last time I checked there was no web control for the product.  It does an excellent job of providing Excel capability for processing large amounts of data.

Good luck.  I think you will find a good solution since you seem to have a good grasp of the pro's and con's of all the different potential solutions.